# Python - Anova test in multiple loops

Tags: python, pandas, loops, statsmodels, anova

In my data frame I have few categorical variables and few continuous variables. I want to perform Anova analysis (anova_lm) for every combination of categorical and continuous variable. So far I was only able to create loop for 1 target categorical with all continuous variables as predictors, like this:

I have my original dataset pima with these columns:

> GENDER - categorical
> AGE - continuous
> EDUCATION - categorical
> INCOME - categorical
> RATE_INTEREST - continuous
> SPD - categorical
> TPD - categorical
> AMT_ANNUITY - continuous
> DOWNPAYMPERC - continuous

From data set I have defined pima_cont, which contains only continuous variables.
From data set I have also defined pima_categ, which contains only categorical variables.

```
keys = []
tables = []
for variable in pima_cont.columns:
    model = ols('{} ~ EDUCATION'.format(variable), data=pima).fit()
    anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)

    keys.append(variable)
    tables.append(anova_table)

df_anova = pd.concat(tables, keys=keys, axis=0)
print(df_anova)
```

Here I have to manually edit my target in this part of the statement `model = ols('{} ~ EDUCATION'.format(variable), data=pima).fit()`

Any tips how this could be automated, so Python would show me same output but for all my categorical variables as targets?

Thanks a lot!
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a multiIndex, just using a 2 x 2 example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

pima = pd.DataFrame({'EDUCATION':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],100),
                     'GENDER':np.random.choice(['M','F'],100),
                    'AGE':np.random.randn(100),
                    'RATE_INTEREST':np.random.randn(100)})
```

Make a multi-index for the possible combinations:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['AGE','RATE_INTEREST'],['EDUCATION','GENDER']],
                                   names=['cont', 'cat'])
index

MultiIndex([(          'AGE', 'EDUCATION'),
            (          'AGE',    'GENDER'),
            ('RATE_INTEREST', 'EDUCATION'),
            ('RATE_INTEREST',    'GENDER')],
           names=['cont', 'cat'])
```

Then similar to what you have above:

```
tables = []
for cont_var,cat_var in index:
    model = ols('{} ~ {}'.format(cont_var,cat_var), data=pima).fit()
    anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)

    tables.append(anova_table)

df_anova = pd.concat(tables, keys=index, axis=0)
```

Final table looks like this:

```
                                      sum_sq    df         F    PR(>F)
AGE           EDUCATION EDUCATION   0.358636   2.0  0.196421  0.821993
                        Residual   88.554164  97.0       NaN       NaN
              GENDER    GENDER      0.258418   1.0  0.285659  0.594226
                        Residual   88.654382  98.0       NaN       NaN
RATE_INTEREST EDUCATION EDUCATION   0.021586   2.0  0.012325  0.987752
                        Residual   84.942705  97.0       NaN       NaN
              GENDER    GENDER      0.656981   1.0  0.763684  0.384315
                        Residual   84.307310  98.0       NaN       NaN
```